# how to connect to remote MS SQL Server using mssql

Tags: php, sql-server

Trying to connect to a remote MS SQL server from a goDaddy server.  The server I am trying to connect from does not have the PDO driver for  SQL Server.  The only option I saw was using mssql. My connction code is as follows

```
$server = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,1433'; //public IP of the SQL server

// Connect to MSSQL
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'username', '*******');

if (!$link) {
    die(mssql_get_last_message());
}
```

The connects fails every time.  Error Unable to connect to server. There is a firewall in place on the Server host SQL Server but I whitelisted the goDaddy IP so that should not be an issue.  Also not seeing anything hit the firewall when I try the script.

Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: just an FYI godaddy tag is destined to die should not use it [read more about it here] (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331817/should-we-burninate-godaddy)

Comment: don't output a fixed(useless) error message, have the system TELL you why it failed: `die(mssql_get_last_message())`

Comment: Sorry I had php errors turned on so was seeing the error on my end. Unable to connect to server is the error

Comment: Actually mssql_get_last_message() returns nothing @MarcB

Comment: You need to ask your hosting provider about this issue. Every provider have their own policy

Comment: Actually resolved it.  GoDaddy gave you the ability to add mssql in the C-panel php settings but didn't actually have the drivers installed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually resolved it. GoDaddy gave you the ability to add mssql in the C-panel php settings but didn't actually have the drivers installed. So no connection was ever attempted with remote server